# How to change the rotation of Progress bar programmatically

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a Progress bar that is working just fine as expected. But there is a button which is doing the specific work. I am just trying to do the following thing

**What I want :**

I want that When I click on button the movement of circular clock wise rotating progress bar to change in anti clock wise rotation. So to engage user that he is doing some work on scree.

**this is what I tried:**

**clock_wise.xml**

> res > anim > clock_wise.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


 <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:drawable="@drawable/iconloading"
    android:toDegrees="1080" />
```

**clock_wise.xml**

> res > anim > anticlock_wise.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:drawable="@drawable/iconloading"
    android:toDegrees="180" />
```

and this is how I set the progressbar in xml

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/loading_rotation"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

> Now the question is I want to toggle between the rotations by using this single progress bar.